# MSDN Release Candidate builds (Windows 7, Windows 2008 R2 et al)

Tags: msdn

Are release candidate builds from MSDN Premium time limited like the public release candidate builds?  I cannot find any warnings or notices to that effect within the MSDN Premium subscriber download area, or during installs of the software.

Comment: Not programming related. Should be closed.

Comment: Ok, add Visual Studio 2010 to the list...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing terms rather than programming.

Comment: Nice of you to notice that on something I asked 5 years ago, before SO fractured into the multitude of sites it is now... looking at the date something was asked gives you context as to whether it was actually off topic at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every nonfinal microsoft product is timebombed.